# Laravel 5.2 Controller middleware for more than one role

Tags: php, laravel-5, roles, middleware

I have a roles administrator, moderator and member in my laravel application. Application have fronted and backend sections. I want to allow access to backend section only for administrator and moderator. I create SuperUsersMiddleware:

```
<?php

namespace CMS\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SuperUsersMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole('administrator') || ! $request->user()->hasRole('moderator')) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register in Kernel.php:

```
......
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'superusers' => \CMS\Http\Middleware\SuperUsersMiddleware::class,
        'administrator' => \CMS\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
        'moderator' => \CMS\Http\Middleware\ModeratorMiddleware::class,
        'auth' => \CMS\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \CMS\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
.....
```

and in my backend folder I create Controller.php (all other controllers in backend section extends this controller) and in __construct() function set middleware:

```
...
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('superusers');
    }
...
```

But this doesn't work for me. I also create administrator and moderator middleware and it works separately but I needed both - together. How to do that? I tray:

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('administrator');
     $this->middleware('moderator');
}
```

But this also can't work. What is a best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 2):

First off I wouldn't apply any Middleware on your master `Controller` as then middleware would be applied to everything. You should do this on each individual controller like `UserController`.

You can apply as many middleware instances to a route/function as you want. I'm not aware of any limitations on that. So I'm not sure why you say this doesn't work:

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('administrator');
     $this->middleware('moderator');
}
```

You can apply the different middleware to the routes that require the different levels. You can do this in your `routes.php` or in your Controllers. If you want to do it in your Controller like you are doing above you would have something like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth'); //this applies to all actions
    $this->middleware('administrator', ['only' => ['adminFunction', 'otherAdminFunction','bothCanAccess']]);
    $this->middleware('moderator',['only' => ['moderatorFunction','bothCanAccess']);
}

public function adminfunction()
{
    ...
}

public function otherAdminfunction()
{
    ...
}

public function moderatorFunction()
{
    ...
}

public function bothCanAccess()
{
    ...
}
```

So first off the `auth` middleware will apply to all actions. This means a user has to be logged in to access any function in here. Then you can apply specific middleware to each function. If you need more info on this check out the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#controller-middleware

To do this in your router you would do something like this:

```
Route::get('/admin', ['middleware' => ['auth', 'administrator'],'uses'=>'Controller@adminFunction']);
```

So in this case it will apply the `auth` middleware first to make sure someone is logged in, then fire the `administrator` middleware and make sure the user is an admin.

Hopefully that helps.